# CSS: Self organising flex items

Tags: html, css

I've a problem. I'm currently building a dashboard like this here https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-dashboard/examples/dashboard.html. Currently I've this HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

What I want to do now is to find a way to get a 2 column layout in flex so that the items are not just under each other. The problem is, that my section items are not static, they are dynamic and different for a specific user role. Also they have different heights.

So is there a way to deal with this? Maybe there is a way to get the sections order them selfs?

The plan would be to apply a 2 column layout when the size of the screen is bigger 1300px:

```
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
    ...
}
```

So is anyone out there who has an idea how I can get this done?

Comment: you can do it with flex if you wrap each pair of columns in a separate flex container and have each column set at 50% width or flex-basis. If you don't want to do that you could consider using grid instead of flex

Comment: I also thought this but I can't wrap them because they are not always visible because of different roles and states. Otherwise this would be a solution, I know. Or is it possible?

Comment: I think you would need to dynamically build the rows in your server application. so you would have `<section class="row flex"><article class="modify_users"><article class="view_users"></section><section class="row flex"><article class="modify_system"><article class="view_system"></section>` for admin and `<section class="row flex"><article class="view_users"><article class="view_system"></section>` for less privileged roles

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://codepen.io/pen/oNvwKRv

```css
.layout {
    column-count: 2;
    padding: 20px;
    /*Spacing between items*/
    font-size: 20px;
}

.item {
    break-inside: avoid;
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.item:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```